# How to indent multiple JSON files via terminal

Tags: python, json, bash, indentation

Is there a quick way to indent a given set of JSON files under a current directory via terminal, similarly to using "Pretty JSON" or "Indent JSON" plugins on Sublime text?

Either by a shell script or python script, etc. ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having python:

```
 echo '{"foo": "bar"}' | python -m json.tool
```

Or [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/):

```
echo '{"foo": "bar"}' | jq .
```

Now replacing every JSON file in the directory:

```
 ls *.json | xargs -I % sh -c "cat % | python -m json.tool > %.new ; mv %.new %"
```